# Making a binary file executable for Snappy Laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, snappy

I'm trying to use Snappy with Laravel to generate PDF documents from HTML. I've included the packges in my composer.json file as such:

"barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "0.2.x",
"h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x"

Composer install runs fine, but when trying to create a pdf I'm getting this error:
The exit status code '126' says something went wrong: stderr: "sh: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site.com/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf‌​-amd64: cannot execute binary file

Is there some other configuration or permissions update I need to make?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I am also experiencing the same issue.